# How to remove focus of edit text in recyclerview on selection of spinner in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-spinner

I have an recyclerview whose layout contains Edittext, spinners , Textviews. The problem is when I select spinner of last items recyclerview list scrolls to top and focused on 1st edit text or selected edittext.

So how to stop scrolling to the focused edittext after selecting spinner?
This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tiny_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tiny_margin"
    android:elevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_blue_color">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_empInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="3.5">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_empName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Asad Umer\n(0123456)"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_designation"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Senior English Teacher"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Subject 1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_SelectSub1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Subject 2"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_SelectSub2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textAlignment="center">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reason"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_SelectReason"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_spinner_dropdown"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_Comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_empInfo"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:visibility="visible"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                android:hint="Enter Comment here ..."
                android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
                android:nextFocusUp="@id/et_comment"
                android:nextFocusLeft="@id/et_comment"
                android:lines="3"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:maxLength="100"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb"
                android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@drawable/scrollbar_track"
                android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_addComment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll_empInfo"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/add_comment" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I think you are using `notifyDatasetChanged()` of adapter try removing that.

Comment: no i am not using notifyDatasetChanged() method i am only using interface to update list on activity

Answer (score 0):

step 1:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

step 2: in your `onBindViewHolder` add:

```
if (myMap.containsKey(position)) {
    spinner.setSelection(myMap.get(position));
}
```

step 3: inside your `onItemSelected`

```
myMap.put(position, selectedIndex);
```